# Theorem numeration shift

Tags: numbering, theorems, counters

I would like to numerate my theorems not by chapters but by shifted chapters in such a way that the theorems in chapter 2 would read Theorem 1.1, Theorem 1.2 and so on.

I need something along the lines of

```
\newteorem{thm}{Theorem}["chapter - 1"]
```

where I don't know the correct syntax for `"chapter - 1"`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's rather unclear why you want such a numbering that I find confusing.

Comment: Maybe you need this weird theorem numbering because you haven't numbered the chapters the way you want to. Perhaps use `\chapter*` for an introduction or preface, so the real chapter numbers start at 1 and not 2.

Comment: Your readers will not thank you for this:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this confusing for the reader; a simple way to get it is as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thethm}{%
  \number\numexpr\value{chapter}-1\relax.\arabic{thm}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{No theorems}

\chapter{With theorems}

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
This one too.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

While I cannot speak for the usefulness of such a numbering, a possible solution is using the [`aliascnt`](http://ctan.org/pkg/aliascnt) package:

```
\documentlcass{scrbook}

\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\newaliascnt{shiftchap}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\theshiftchap}{\addtocounter{shiftchap}{-1}%
  \arabic{shiftchap}\addtocounter{shiftchap}{1}}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[shiftchap]

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\begin{thm}test\end{thm}

\begin{thm}test2\end{thm}

\chapter{test2}

\begin{thm}test 3\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

should provide the desired output.

In this case, an alias of the chapter counter is made and the display of *that* counter is one less than the value of the counter.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I do not really understand the use you might have of such a functionality, here is how I would do:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]

\newenvironment{mythm}{%
\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}%
\begin{thm}}%
{%
\end{thm}
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{First Part}

\begin{mythm}
Here is my theorem
\end{mythm}

\end{document}
```

The *trick* is to redefine the `thm` environment such as it decreases the chapter counter by 1 at its beginning and increases this counter by 1 at its end.